# Opening a local pdf file using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, electron

I am attempting to make a pdf viewer app using electron and electron-pdf-window
the code below works when i want to open from a URL file path, but when i tried to open a pdf from my local files using the `file:///` the application download the pdf instead of viewing it on my window.

```
const { app } = require('electron')
const PDFWindow = require('electron-pdf-window')

app.on('ready', () => {
  const win = new PDFWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  win.loadURL('file://///C://username/desktop/myfile.pdf')
})
```

I tried also below code but below error displays.

> TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
const PDFWindow = require('electron-pdf-window')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

PDFWindow.addSupport(win)

win.loadURL('file://///C://username/desktop/myfile.pdf')
```

Is there another way to open local pdf files from my PC directory?

Comment: have you tried this? https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

Comment: @AlleoIndong i tried it but got a error `Cannot create BrowserWindow before app is ready`

Comment: make sure you put the code inside `app.on('ready', function() {}`

Comment: @AlleoIndong sorry i am so noob, i got it working thanks! you should post a answer so i can accept it, putting inside the `app.on('ready', function() {}` got it to working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on this readme, https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

you can do it something like

`` win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`) ``

but you have to put this inside `app.on('ready', function() {}` to avoid getting the `Cannot create BrowserWindow before app is ready` error.

**Reason why that error appears**
Because the app is not yet ready and is still loading

Answer (score 0):

You need Modify electron-pdf-window package.

Open electron-pdf-window/index.js

Go to comment line 23  `const->let fileUrl = url.replace(/^file:///i, '');`

firstly change const via let,then add after this code

`fileUrl = fileUrl.replace('/', '');`

you can use normally ;

`const w= new BrowserWindow({
width: 1200,
height: 920,
webPreferences: {
nodeIntegration: true,
contextIsolation: true
}
});`
   `PDFWindow.addSupport(w)`

`w.loadURL(url.format ({
pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../pdf/123.pdf'),
protocol: 'file:',
slashes: true
}));`